# Create var from text string

Tags: javascript, string

My apologies if this make no sense. I am new to JavaScript.

I am trying to create a variable form a text string. I know I can use `email.body_text`, `indexOf()` and `substring()` if the text is same in all instances. However its a date an will be different each time emails is received.

In the below code the `var date` is text string I have type. However, this `var date` needs to be a position from a text file.

```
var date = "25th June 2014 00:30 – 03:30";
var monthlist = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
str = date.split(' ');
var day = str[0].substring(0,2);
var year = str[2];
var sh = str[3];
var eh = str [5];
var comp = str[1].substring(0,3)+' '+day+' '+year;
```

A brief example...

Date & Change Window:

25th June 2014 00:30 – 03:30 BST

(24th June 2014 23:30 – 25th June 2014 02:30 GMT)

30 minutes downtime for hardware replacement and restoration

15 minutes downtime for software upgrade and restoration

I am trying to place the 2nd line 25th June as `var date`

Thank you.

Comment: What is your end goal? Please show some code.

Comment: Some code demonstrating what you want to achieve might help

Comment: Use a regular expression?

Comment: Good questions give good details. You are lacking examples of what this mystery string is.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. But for a `Date` object you can use the `.toDateString()` method. `var myString = myDate.toDateString()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure I understand what you're asking but I also feel like you're complicating things.

This might be what you're looking for:

```
date = "25th June 2014 00:30 – 03:30",
date = date.slice(0,9);
```

You use the slice() method to extract text. The 0 is the starting position of the string and the 9 is the ending position that you want to extract. This will give you "25th June" in the date variable.

Comment: Thank you jmin91. I have the split because the date is converted to short format (dd-mm-yyyy). My main issue is that the script needs to pick the line after "Date & Change Window:" and place it as `var date`. If the date was in the same string as  "Date & Change Window:" e.g. "Date & Change Window: 25th June 2014 00:30 – 03:30" I could have done this...`var search = email.body_text.indexOf(Change Window: ');`
`var text = email.body_text.substring(search + 22, search + 50);`
`var date = text;`.